# Django Dynamic form for manytomany relationship

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I am trying to make a form which includes the functionality of `Add/Delete Row`. And I am following [this](https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/13553/how-can-i-save-django-dynamic-formset-data-using-forms-and-views) tutorial.

The problem that I am facing is that I am unable to show the `Add` or `remove` button as well as the input fields in the form.

Screenshot:

[image]

Here's the template:

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>gffdfdf</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <form action="" method="post" class="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2> Team</h2>
        {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} : {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ form.players.management_form }}

        <h3> Product Instance(s)</h3>
        <table id="table-product" class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>player name</th>
                <th>highest score</th>
                <th>age</th>
            </tr>

            </thead>
            {% for player in form.players %}
            <tbody class="player-instances">

            <tr>
                <td>{{ player.pname }}</td>
                <td>{{ player.hscore }}</td>
                <td>{{ player.age }}</td>
                <td><input id="input_add" type="button" name="add" value=" Add More "
                           class="tr_clone_add btn data_input"></td>
            </tr>

            </tbody>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>

    </form>
</div>
<script>
    var i = 1;
    $("#input_add").click(function () {
        $("tbody tr:first").clone().find(".data_input").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('class') == 'tr_clone_add btn data_input') {
                $(this).attr({
                    'id': function (_, id) {
                        return "remove_button"
                    },
                    'name': function (_, name) {
                        return "name_remove" + i
                    },
                    'value': 'Remove'
                }).on("click", function () {
                    var a = $(this).parent();
                    var b = a.parent();
                    i = i - 1
                    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(i);
                    b.remove();

                    $('.player-instances tr').each(function (index, value) {
                        $(this).find('.data_input').each(function () {
                            $(this).attr({
                                'id': function (_, id) {
                                    var idData = id;
                                    var splitV = String(idData).split('-');
                                    var fData = splitV[0];
                                    var tData = splitV[2];
                                    return fData + "-" + index + "-" + tData
                                },
                                'name': function (_, name) {
                                    var nameData = name;
                                    var splitV = String(nameData).split('-');
                                    var fData = splitV[0];
                                    var tData = splitV[2];
                                    return fData + "-" + index + "-" + tData
                                }
                            });
                        })
                    })
                })
            } else {
                $(this).attr({
                    'id': function (_, id) {
                        var idData = id;
                        var splitV = String(idData).split('-');
                        var fData = splitV[0];
                        var tData = splitV[2];
                        return fData + "-" + i + "-" + tData
                    },
                    'name': function (_, name) {
                        var nameData = name;
                        var splitV = String(nameData).split('-');
                        var fData = splitV[0];
                        var tData = splitV[2];
                        return fData + "-" + i + "-" + tData
                    }
                });

            }
        }).end().appendTo("tbody");
        $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(1 + i);
        i++;

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me figure out what the code is missing, I tried the solution given in comments too but that only solves the `input` fields problem

Comment: I think the error might be coming from the fact that the add button does not have a <th> mentioned. When you render the page go you see the code same in the inspect of the browser in chrome.

Comment: Can you also post your forms.py?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by looping through the last row added to the table and then updating all id & name attributes with new incremented i value like:

```
$("tbody tr:last :input").each(function() {
   $(this).attr({
      'id': function(_, id) {
        return id.replace(/\d/g, i)
      },
      'name': function(_, name) {
        return name.replace(/\d/g, i)
      }
   })
})
```

Also as Paul mentioned change `players` to `player`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't reproduced your code so I can't be sure, but when I look at your models I read:

```
class PlayerForm(forms.Form):
    pname = forms.CharField()
    hscore= forms.IntegerField()
    age = forms.IntegerField()

PlayerFormset= formset_factory(PlayerForm)

class TeamForm(forms.Form):
   tname= forms.CharField()
   player= PlayerFormset()
```

You pass the Teamform to the template in the variable form. That means you can access the  individual player forms with:

```
{% for player in form.player %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

In your code I read form.players instead of form.player. Also at the top I read form.players.management_form. Django will not recognize these variables so return empty values. You can check this by looking at the HTML elements in your browser. In the example in the comments in the link you provided it says correctly form.player. I am not sure why in that case the add / remove button would not show.